# Can one Jenkins Trigger a job on a remote jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 Jenkins hosts, and would like First Jenkins to trigger a job on remote Jenkins based on "SUCCESS" in result on the first one.
I have looked at various plugins , but they all seem to indicate ONE Jenkins host, where multiple jobs can be chained in this manner.

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile, a jenkins plugin became available which makes it a lot easier:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: This plugin is unmaintained and doesn't support jobs that are in folders.  Keep that in mind

Comment: This plugin does support folders and as of this writing looks to have been actively maintained since May 2018.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to do using cURL requests, no need for plugins or master>slave relations. It took me 5 minutes from beginning to start.
Use the following manual:

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a downstream job on host1 that only builds if first job on host1 succeeds.
In this job you would trigger a remote build much like i described it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11557932/1529272)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Install following plugins in both Jenkins.**

1. Generic Webhook Trigger: Job can be triggered from http request.
2. HTTP Request Plugin: To send http request as build step
3. Any Build Step Plugin: To use any build step in post-build action.

**Step 2: Configure job to be triggered(Jenkins B).**

- Select generic webhook trigger in build trigger and generate a token and paste.
- After saving this job can be triggered by sending a http request to 
  http://JENKINS_B_URL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=TOKEN_VALUE

**Step 3: In master Jenkins(Jenkins A) configure flexible publish settings in configure system to allow use all build steps as post build actions.**

**Step 4: In post build actions add another step “Flexible publish”.** 
Using this any build action can be used as post-build action. Add a HTTP Request action.
Provide Jenkins B webhook url in url field and save.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Configure your Jenkins nodes and label them, say `master`and `slave` (Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes).

1) Configure `Job A` and specify that it can only run on `master` ("Restrict where this project can be run" and in the label field put `master`).

2) Configure `Job B` so that it is only triggered if `Job A` is successful:

"Post-build Actions" -> "Trigger only if build succeeds"

3) Pin `Job B` to `slave` similar to step 1.

Comment: BOTH the Jenkins are Masters in my case, and there IS no slave. Since as far as i understand a slave need NOT have Jenkins installed, but rather have a conduit where Master Jenkins Executes commands on remote and gets results via ssh, or other means. So how would this work with multiple masters ?

Comment: It wouldn't. In this case, you could add a post-build step (e.g. execute a shell script or Groovy) and invoke the second build via a URL.