# Trigger jenkins job slave server

Tags: jenkins

I have the following jenkin scenario:

1. Jenkins server **MainBuild** : it is the master server
2. Jenkins server **FirstSlave**: it is slave of **MainBuild**
3. Jenkins server **SecondSlave**: it is a slave of **FirstSlave**

It is possible to trigger a job from **MainBuild** server to **SecondSlave**?

The reason for the previus setup is the following

The reason for the setup is the following:

1. the jenkins server **MainBuild** is in the network A
2. the Jenkins servers **FirstSlave** and **SecondSlave** are in the network B
3. for security reason from network A I can open the port only for a Jenkins slave in network B
4. I need the server **SecondSlave** because i have some devices connected to the same pc where the second slave is running, and these device are used in some test triggererd by the  **SecondSlave**

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you have this setup ?  It would be easier to trigger your job if it was defined on MainBuild.

Comment: You can trigger any remote server job as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11557932/1361089